# how to create multiple web socket servers on one physical server

Tags: java, websocket

I need to load test the web socket client/server. For this I would like to simulate 100 web socket servers. How do I achieve that in java? Also, I only have handful of physical servers. can I create those 100 web sockets on 100 different ports on the same server via threading?
Here is the sample URL of the socket server I connect to.
ws://myserver.com:8025/websockets/test
so, can I create 100 of these with different port numbers (replace 8025 with 8026, 8027 etc)

Comment: Why don't you try it and find out?